# How do I check if an ID is a number?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have if statement that I need to modify so that it checks if Statute ID is a number (123654) etc.

If Statute ID is not a number error message should say **"Statute ID Value is not a number"**

**vb.net code**

```
 'Check to see if we got statuteId and make sure the Id string length is > than 0
        If Not objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:StatuteId/ss:Id[string-length(.)>0]", objXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing Then
```

**Sample xml document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetStatuteRequest>
    <Statute>
        <StatuteId> 
           <ID>15499</ID>
        </StatuteId>
    </Statute>
</GetStatuteRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I can see from your question and Steve's answer, you need/want something like this...

```
Dim node As XmlNode = objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:StatuteId/ss:Id[string-length(.)>0]", objXMLNameSpaceManager)
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(node.InnerText) Then
        //...Do Stuff
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Statute ID Value is not a number")
    End If
Else
    //... Do Something Else
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to transform a string in a number is through the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This method checks if your string is a valid integer number and if not then return false without throwing any performance costly exception.

So your code could be simply written in this way

```
Dim doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load("D:\TEMP\DATA.XML")


Dim statuteID  = doc.GetElementsByTagName( "ID" )
Dim id = statuteID.Item(0).InnerXml

Dim result As Integer
if Not Int32.TryParse(id, result) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Statute ID Value is not a number")
Else
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString())
End If
```

Of course a lot of checks need to be added around the loading and parsing of the XML file but this is not the argument of your question

Comment: Steve thanks for your help. The only problem I have is that my boss want me to do it the way I how the If statement here. And then throw an exception with the message I posted earlier. You way seems better but they won't let me do it that way!

Comment: It is not clear. Your code tries to evaluate the string length, not  if the string is a number. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx) function:

```
Private Function IsIdNumeric(ByVal strXmlDocumentFileNameAndPath As String) As Boolean

    Return ((From xmlTarget As XElement
             In XDocument.Load(New System.IO.StreamReader(strXmlDocumentFileNameAndPath)).Elements("GetStatuteRequest").Elements("Statute").Elements("StatuteId").Elements("ID")
             Where IsNumeric(xmlTarget.Value)).Count > 0)

End Function
```

Then call it like this:

```
    If Not IsIdNumeric("C:\Some\File\Path.xml") Then

        Throw New Exception("Statute ID Value is not a number")

    End If
```